# Detect autofill for Edge browser

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, autofill

Edge browser recently released support for autofill and I wanna apply the same custom style I have for Chrome in Edge, but apparently the tag `:-webkit-autofill` doesn't work. Can someone help me on what to do in this case? I've spend half a day searching for the correct tag, but I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution and what Edge does is that it includes a class called `edge-autofilled` in the input.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution for this issue. I suggest you to try to mark your own answer as an accepted answer for this question after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.